# Sign a string with an RSA private key

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my app i have to sign a message with an RSA private key i already have. After this done, i want to use the signature later. 
I've checked several libraries, but all of them do much more that i need.
This is what i'd like to do:

```
NSString *message = @"This is a message";
NSString *privateKey = ...;

NSString *signature = [self signMessage:message withPrivateKey:privateKey];
```

How would

```
(NSString *)signMessage:(NSString *)message withPrivateKey:(NSString *)privateKey {
}
```

look like?

Comment: Isn't RSA an encryption algorithm rather than a digest algorithm?

Comment: it is. i want the token generated with the private key.

Comment: I don't think this is what you are after. You would sign something with a message digest/hash. Here you seem to be combining public-private key encryption and hashing.

Comment: It's very much possible. What i need to develop is the iOS alternative of this php code:
$rsa->sign("This is a message")

Comment: `$rsa` is an identifier.  That code could just as easily be `$sha1->sign("This is a message")`.

Answer (score 3):

iOS has a C API for doing this.  I've never used it myself, but it looks like you need a PKCS12 formatted file with the private key in it which you import with [SecKeyPKCS12Imort](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157-CH1g-SW35) and get the private key out of.  Then the function is [SecKeyRawSign](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157-CH1g-SW5) to sign your string.

The string should first be converted to an NSData object using a known character encoding - probably UTF-8 and the bytes in the NSData signed.

If you use non-ASCII characters in your string, as well as making sure you use a well defined encoding, you also need to be careful of how some characters are represented.  For instance é can be represented as a single Unicode number or as the Unicode acute accent followed by the letter e.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character

Answer (score 3):

I've tried millions of signing methods, that include Keychain, extracting SecKeyRef's, certificates (.p12), .pem key-files, but still didn't manage to achieve my main goal:

- Sign a string-digest using PKCS#1 v1.5 and SHA1
- Use string base64 key received from server (JSON) instead of using certificate-files.

My private key is a PKCS#1 private key formatted like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAKBgQCx9YWznzT3irAArr+INM5m0i6UCNICq4E8yrWwPbGh8/kdU/oh
.....   .....   .....   .....   .....   .....   .....   .....   
eF9lWooBNGgSh5vmkgECQGJwmDLKohSKEtVwGOIp3S3j+CHs0vVnznmtmC9sfrj4
ef48Sx1KFI8iQa3Nfv5bokaJkiIVVx/eMaa96Vracjc=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Eventually I moved to OpenSSL and things got much brighter.
So the whole process looks like the following:

1. Download and build [iOS OpenSSL library](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone).
2. Add the lib to the project.
3. Use OpenSSL to finally sign the message.

---

### Step 1: OpenSSL library

Download the library from https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

Copy build-libssl.sh to your project folder
Using Terminal run the following:

```
cd [your project folder]
/build-libssl.sh
```

### Step 2: adding OpenSSL

Copy the “include” folder from OpenSSL into your project-folder

Drag-copy the libcrypto*.a and libss*.a files into your XCode Folder

Open the Build Settings of your “Target”

Change `Library Search Paths` to `$(inherited) “$(SRCROOT)”`

Change `User Header Search Paths` to `include`

Activate `Always Search User Paths`

### Step 3: Signing

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <iomanip>

- (NSString*) signHeader:(NSString*) pTextString withPrivateKey: (NSString*) pPrivateKey {
    
    int retEr;
    char* text = (char*) [pTextString UTF8String];
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int dataLen;
    
    // converting nsstring base64 private key to openssl RSA key
    
    BIO *mem = NULL;
    RSA *rsa_private = NULL;
    char *private_key = (char*)[pPrivateKey UTF8String];
    
    mem = BIO_new_mem_buf(private_key, strlen(private_key));
    if (mem == NULL)
    {
        char buffer[120];
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenSSL error: %s", buffer);
        exit(0);
    }
    
    rsa_private = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(mem, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free (mem);
    if (rsa_private == NULL)
    {
        char buffer[120];
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenSSL error: %s", buffer);
        exit(0);
    }
    // end of convertion
    
    data = (unsigned char *) text;
    dataLen = strlen(text);
    
    //// creating signature
    // sha1
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char sign[128];
    unsigned int signLen;
    
    SHA1(data, dataLen, hash);
    
    //  signing
    retEr = RSA_sign(NID_sha1, hash, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, sign, &signLen, rsa_private);
    
    //  printf("Signature len gth = %d\n", signLen);
    printf("RSA_sign: %s\n", (retEr == 1) ? "RSA_sign success" : "RSA_sign error");
    
    //  convert unsigned char -> std:string
    std::stringstream buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        buffer << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
        buffer << std::setw(2)  << static_cast<unsigned>(sign[i]);
    }
    std::string signature = buffer.str();
    
    //  convert std:string -> nsstring
    NSString *signedMessage = [NSString stringWithCString:signature.c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    
    RSA_free(rsa_private);
    
    return signedMessage;
}
```

If you want to use SHA256 or any other SHA you must change the following:

```
SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH => SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
sign[128] => sign[256]
SHA1(data, dataLen, hash) => SHA256(data, dataLen, hash)
NID_sha1 => NID_sha256
```

### Alternative Step 3: Signing (Swift)

Since Swift language isn't a superset of C++ it can't be combined with C++ directly, therefore you need to create a Objective-C wrapper of C++ code and then call it (Obj-C) from your Swift code.

#### Step 3.1

Create an Obj-C class for your C++ code.
**IMPORTANT:** the file must be either with .mm extension or set type to `Objective-C++ Source`

**OpenSSLWrapper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OpenSSLWrapper : NSObject
+ (NSString*) signHeader:(NSString*) pTextString withPrivateKey: (NSString*) pPrivateKey;
@end
```

**OpenSSLWrapper.mm**

```
#import "OpenSSLWrapper.h"

#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <iomanip>

@implementation OpenSSLWrapper

+ (NSString*) signHeader:(NSString*) pTextString withPrivateKey: (NSString*) pPrivateKey {
    
    int retEr;
    char* text = (char*) [pTextString UTF8String];
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int dataLen;
    
    // converting nsstring base64 private key to openssl RSA key
    
    BIO *mem = NULL;
    RSA *rsa_private = NULL;
    char *private_key = (char*)[pPrivateKey UTF8String];
    
    mem = BIO_new_mem_buf(private_key, strlen(private_key));
    if (mem == NULL)
    {
        char buffer[120];
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenSSL error: %s", buffer);
        exit(0);
    }
    
    rsa_private = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(mem, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free (mem);
    if (rsa_private == NULL)
    {
        char buffer[120];
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenSSL error: %s", buffer);
        exit(0);
    }
    // end of convertion
    
    data = (unsigned char *) text;
    dataLen = strlen(text);
    
    //// creating signature
    // sha1
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char sign[128];
    unsigned int signLen;
    
    SHA1(data, dataLen, hash);
    
    //  signing
    retEr = RSA_sign(NID_sha1, hash, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, sign, &signLen, rsa_private);
    
    //  printf("Signature len gth = %d\n", signLen);
    printf("RSA_sign: %s\n", (retEr == 1) ? "RSA_sign success" : "RSA_sign error");
    
    //  convert unsigned char -> std:string
    std::stringstream buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        buffer << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
        buffer << std::setw(2)  << static_cast<unsigned>(sign[i]);
    }
    std::string signature = buffer.str();
    
    //  convert std:string -> nsstring
    NSString *signedMessage = [NSString stringWithCString:signature.c_str() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
    
    RSA_free(rsa_private);
    
    return signedMessage;
}

@end
```

#### Step 3.2

Create a Bridging-Header file.

**YourProject-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "OpenSSLWrapper.h"
```

#### Step 3.3

Use the method from Obj-C in your Swift file.

**DigestSignature.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class DigestSignature: NSObject {
    let privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIICXAIBAAKBgQCx9YWznzT3irAArr+INM5m0i6UCNICq4E8yrWwPbGh8/kdU/oh  .....   .....  eF9lWooBNGgSh5vmkgECQGJwmDLKohSKEtVwGOIp3S3j+CHs0vVnznmtmC9sfrj4ef48Sx1KFI8iQa3Nfv5bokaJkiIVVx/eMaa96Vracjc=-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
    var digest: String = OpenSSLWrapper.signHeader("Hello World", withPrivateKey: privateKey) ;
       
}
```

#### In the result, you have a hex NSString* signed digest.

Hope that helps

Comment: Basically this.. OpenSSL was for me the only way to go as well.. That said, it is not a easy job to set up correctly. Only thing I can recommend, are links. This one is to build lib -> https://gist.github.com/foozmeat/5154962 and to use it, do something like this https://gist.github.com/dam5s/3444704

Comment: What would the Swift version of Step3. be?

Comment: @GeoffH Swift isn't a superset of C++, therefore you can't mix Swift and C++ code in one .swift file. You should create a separate Obj-C file-wrapper with this method and import it to your .swift files

Comment: Thanks Roma, is there any chance you would be able to show how this should be wrapped (.h &.mm ?) :/

Comment: @GeoffH done! Step 3 updated with a Swift workaround

Comment: @RomanSlyepko, can you provide a sample project for this.It will be so helpful

Comment: @RomanSlyepko , I am getting this error : https://puu.sh/sauUT/b09dc776b1.png . Any Help?

Comment: @ThihaAung did you write the includes? #include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>